# Summing spreadsheet row values matching column substring

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I know basic summing across rows or columns. I'm now stuck with slightly complex case where I want to sum based on multiple substrings in a column. See attached image. I need to sum the numbers (column C) of all rows where specific column (B) has hashtag. The desired results will look like columns E & F in image.

same sheet here for use https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18nld3quzXqppxw_JWEpSxXvIRcMa1Fv_1WsWwwPfPFE/edit?usp=sharing

[image: Example of input type and desired output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USE SUMIF()

```
=SUMIF(B:B,"*" & E3 & "*",C:C)
```

Works in both Excel and GoogleSheets

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can also place this formula in cell F3 and there will then be no need to copy it to each cell in column F:  `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK( E3:E),,sumif($B$3:$B, "*" & E3:E & "*", $C$3:$C)))`  As long as the cell in column E has a value, the formula will use that value and sum the appropriate cells.

Comment: Yes, in Google sheets you can do what @Karl_S stated and it is less work, But excel will not allow that.